# Thread.sleep() in one thread makes the UI thread go to sleep too

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i have class that extends thread and in one of its methodes i added Thread.sleep(5000) to wait for something, and i start this thread from onCreate() like this

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

MyClass mc = MyClass();
mc.start(); 
mc.join();
// do something

}
```

and in the MyClass run methode i do something like this

```
Class MyClass extends Thread {

public void run() {
sleep(15000);
// do something
}

}
```

the problem that i see the UI thread sleep for 5 second too if i run MyClass thread (that calls the sleep methode), why this happens ?

Comment: This is not possible. There must be something else in your code that is causing the delay.

Comment: what is `mc.Start()`? It should be `mc.start()`

Comment: @Rajath DSouza: i also do join after start (i add it to the code).
@Zombies: Typo fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, here's you problem:

```
mc.join();
```

This makes the current thread (i.e. the UI) wait until the thread represented by `mc` has finished its `run()` method. What were you trying to achieve with the `join()` anyway.

Comment: Yup this is exactly the problem. I swear I did not see .join when I first looked here. The way the code was pasted here, there's no point to having code run in a different thread if you do .start followed by .join

Comment: your right, i focused on sleep and i forget that join will block it ~ i was trying to do something onCreate when the thread finish running, do you any idea how could i do it without join ?

Comment: @Mike dg: your right, if you see the comment under the question i said i add it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing runOnUIThread or using handlers in your MyClass thread?

If you comment the new thread out, does everything work fine?

Comment: No im not doing runOnUIThread or using handlers. and if i comment the thread it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that thread is running on the UI thread. If you want to run in a separate thread, you need to use something like a Runnable or ASyncTask.

Please see http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html